# What is your favorite RPG for younger people?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, roleplaying

I have played a lot of Dungeons and Dragons with my younger siblings, but I have found that they can lose interest quickly with all of the complicated rules and slow combat. They want more of the story and less of the rules. I did some research into other games, but many of them are just as complicated. I want the game to have plenty of action, but it should be clean action as my siblings are all 12 years old and under. I looked into GURPS, as I thought that it would be simpler and more customizable, but it was still very complicated and is so rules-based that I feel that it is lacking the story element. I want to make a campaign myself, and I want it to be based on a great storyline that will allow my siblings to enjoy themselves and get very involved in the story. Any ideas?

Comment: Howdy! Welcome to our stack! Please take our [tour] and if you'd like more info you can also visit the [help]. This question is fairly opinion-based and would fare much better on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449), but you can also hop into our very own [chat] and ask there as well.